# How do I use the [@bs.this] BuckleScript attribute in Reason (ReasonML)?

Tags: ffi, reason, bucklescript

I'm trying to write ReasonML that compiles to this JS:

```
function main(example) {
    example.foo = function() {
        console.log(this)
    }
}
```

Here's my Reason:

```
let module Example = {
    type t;
    external set_foo_method : t => (t => unit [@bs.this]) => unit = "foo" [@@bs.set];
};

let main = fun example => Example.set_foo_method example (fun [@bs.this] x => {
    Js.log(x);
});
```

I'm getting a syntax error on the line and column for the second `[@bs.this]`.

```
File "/Users/maxwellheiber/dev/rerect/src/demo.re", line 6, characters 62-64:
Error: 742: <SYNTAX ERROR>
```

I'm following the BuckleScript docs for [@bs.this](http://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/Manual.html#_bindings_to_code_this_code_based_callbacks_bs_this).

Is the syntax for using BuckleScript to bind to `this` different in Reason as compared to OCaml? The following OCaml (not Reason) with BuckleScript attributes compiles without errors to the correct JS:

```
module Example = struct
    type t
    external set_foo_method : t -> (t -> unit [@bs.this]) -> unit = "foo" [@@bs.set]
end

let main example = Example.set_foo_method example (fun [@bs.this] x -> Js.log(x))
```

How do I use the `[@bs.this]` BuckleScript attribute in Reason to generate JS that uses `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, attribute precedence and such is unfortunately subtly different. [Reason Tools](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-tools) (which is great for converting small snippets like this) says this is what you want:

```
module Example = {
  type t;
  external set_foo_method : t => (t => unit) [@bs.this] => unit = "foo" [@@bs.set];
};

let main example => Example.set_foo_method example ((fun x => Js.log x) [@bs.this]);
```

It will compile to

```
function main(example) {
  example.foo = (function () {
      var x = this ;
      console.log(x);
      return /* () */0;
    });
  return /* () */0;
}
```